# C++ LinkedList Swap Nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [debug help - swap 2 nodes of double link list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306267/debug-help-swap-2-nodes-of-double-link-list)

I'm trying to write an algorithm that can swap two nodes in a singly linkedlist in C++. Here's what i have so far:

```
void swap(ListNode *node1, ListNode *node2)
{
    ListNode *prev1 = head;
    ListNode *prev2 = head;

    //Search previous node for node1:
    while(prev1->next!=node1 || prev1 != node1)
        prev1 = prev1->getNext();

    //Search previous node for node2:
    while(prev2->next!=node2 || prev2 != node2)
        prev2 = prev2->getNext();


    if(node1->next==node2)
    {  //This means node1 == prev2?
        tail = node1;
        node1->next = NULL;
        head = node2;
        node2->next = node1;
    }
    else if(node2->next==node1)
    {  // node2 == prev1
        tail = node2; 
        node2->next = NULL;
        head = node1;
        node1->next = node2;
    }
    if(node1->next == NULL)
    {   //node1 is last
        node1->next = node2->next;
        tail = node2;
        node2->next = NULL;
        prev1->next = node2;
        prev2->next = node1;
    }
}
```

But I realized the number of different cases I can get, like if there LL was only two elements, or if they gave us node 2 before node 1, etc etc. I realized it can't be this complicated and ugly. So how do you write an algorithm to swap two nodes?

Comment: What is the *specific* question?

Comment: We don't "give a few tips" on Stack Overflow (which is not a web forum or message board). We answer specific questions about programming languages.

Comment: "How do you swap two nodes in a linked list" sounds like a pretty legit and concrete question to me, albeit a duplicate.

Comment: I cannot say that this is not a duplicate, but it is not a duplicate of the linked question. This question is about a single link list, not a doubly linked list

Comment: For a single link list, my advice would be to use an extra level of indirection to find the positions for the swaps (pointer to the pointer to node that you want to swap) that extra level simplify the number of cases a great deal. After you have the two positions, you can just swap the pointers to the nodes and the pointers to the next nodes. Should not take more than 10-15 lines with just two loops and a couple of ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Doing the whole task in one routine is wrong.  Break it down into two simpler problems:

1) Remove a node from a list, including all special cases.
2) Insert a node in a list, including all special cases.

From there, the overall problem is easy, but since this is obviously homework, you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This seems cleaner to me:

```
//Maybe this function should go instide ListNode itself...

ListNode *prev(ListNode *node) {

    if (node == head)
        return null;

    ListNode *search = head;

    while (search != node)
       search = search->getNext();

    return search;
}

void swap(ListNode *node1, ListNode *node2)
{
    ListNode *prev1 = prev(node1), 
             *prev2 = prev(node2),
             *next1 = node1->getNext(),
             *next2 = node2->getNext();

    if (prev1)
        prev1->next = node2;
    else
        head = node2;

    if (prev2)
        prev2->next = node1;
    else
        head = node1;

    if (!next1)
        tail = node2;
    else if (!next2)
        tail = node1;

    node1->next = next2;
    node2->next = next1;
}
```

Haven't tested this ofc...

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct llist {
        struct llist *next;
        char *payload;
        } llists[]=
{{ llists+1, "one"}
,{ llists+2, "two"}
,{ llists+3, "three"}
,{ llists+4, "four"}
,{ llists+5, "five"}
,{ llists+6, "six"}
,{ llists+7, "seven"}
,{ llists+8, "eight"}
,{ llists+9, "nine"}
,{ NULL, "ten"}
 };

struct llist *head = llists;

void llistswap(struct llist *one, struct llist * two)
{
struct llist **hnd, **h1, **h2;

h1 = h2 = NULL;

for (hnd= &head; *hnd; hnd = &(*hnd)->next) {
    struct llist *tmp;
    if ((*hnd) == one) h1 = hnd;
    else if ((*hnd) == two) h2 = hnd;
    else continue;
    if (!h1 || !h2) continue;

    tmp =  *h1;
    *h1 = *h2;
    *h2 = tmp;

    tmp = (*h1)->next;
    (*h1)->next = (*h2)->next;
    (*h2)->next =  tmp;
    break;
    }
}

void do_print(struct llist *lp)
{
for ( ; lp; lp = lp->next) {
    printf("%s%c", lp->payload, (lp->next) ?',' : '\n' );
    }   
}

int main(void)
{
do_print (head);
llistswap ( llists+4, llists+7);
do_print (head);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP asks about a doubly-linked list, not single. And this code is not self-explanatory enough to warrant having no description whatsoever.

Comment: Well, it is homework anyway, so adding the updates to the backpointers (while we're at it) seems trivial.

Comment: BTW: both the title and the question don't mention double linked lists, nor ->prev pointers. (there are some variables called prev[12], but these seem to serve another purpose)

Comment: @tenfour where does the question mention *double* or *prev*? The first line of the actual question does mention *single* though. Maybe you rushed into the comment  and the vote to close...

Comment: true; i seem to be blind or got confused with another question. my bad.